# Add Parameters in Uiwebview in ios with swift

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, swift

Hello Friends My name is Tony dhand. I am new in IOS development. Now i am developing a IOS project with UIWebview. But i have some problems i want to pass the Parameters in this. I am using local html page for this. I want to pass the username and password with that my code is below:

> @IBOutlet weak var Webviewholder: UIWebView!

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    let localfilePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("myweb/index", withExtension: "html");

    self.Webviewholder.delegate = self


    let myRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: localfilePath!);
    Webviewholder.loadRequest(myRequest);





    self.view.addSubview(Webviewholder)

    self.Webviewholder.frame = self.view.bounds
    self.Webviewholder.scalesPageToFit = false}
```

I want to the result like  index.html?username=asd&password=******

If this is possible please help as soon as possible or give your suggestions

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can generate URL like below code,

```
let urlString = NSString(format: "username=%@&password=%@", USERNAME, PASSWORD)
let localfilePath = NSURL(string: "myweb/index.html?\(urlString)")
print(localfilePath)
```

Try like this. Hope it will be help to you.

Comment: sorry this is not working it is unable to show the page in UIWebview it shows only white screen

Comment: Please check your url once. Is it generating properly? Or you should check directly via passing url string in NSUrlRequest.

Comment: I read the code very carefully your code is right it show the output like this Optional(myweb/index.html?username=123&password=123)   but it is unable to load the page is always show only white screen    let urlString = NSString(format: "username=%@&password=%@", "123", "123")
        let localfilePaths = NSURL(string: "myweb/index.html?\(urlString)")
       print(localfilePaths)
         let myRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: (localfilePaths)!);
            Webviewholder.loadRequest(myRequest);

Comment: Ok then first you have to create correct url string then it will work

Comment: when i use this method  let localfilePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("myweb/index", withExtension: "html");   it works properly but when i use above method it show white screen . i am unable to crate right syntax can u help me my project is in the Document/Apps/GGC/Mypro/myweb/index.html

Comment: NSBundle.URLForResource - only returns files that are bundled in your application at build/compile time, like when you drag a file into your Xcode project and add it to your app target. You can typically use this when your app comes preloaded with resources you need, like images, movies, databases, and other files.

Comment: ok if my html file location is     GGC/Myapp/myweb/index.html   then the url look like    let localfilePaths = NSURL(string: "myweb/index.html?\(urlString)") is this right or wrong   GGC is main folder Myapp is the project name and other is the folder that contain all html files and images   so tell me this is right or wrong

Comment: if your file located in your resources then you can use it like, NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("index", withExtension: "html")
and if you are working with real time URL which can work in browser then you can use it like, NSURL(string: "YOUR_URL/myweb/index.html?\(urlString)")

Comment: bro i am using the resources and want to pass the parameters i do'nt want to use the url from any server url i think you don't get my problem . I want to  generate a login from my resource html file i create the login after the login i want to display the user profile for that i want to pass the user id or username and password that i had stored in local in app so i want some code that will pass parameters to my resource html files